# detect overflow after \begin{sloppypar} ... \end{sloppypar}

Tags: margins

Some of my paragraphs overflow into the margins (some words or lines are just unbreakable because they are things like "(123,2323,23123,123123)". I am using `\begin{sloppypar} ... \end{sloppypar}` to wrap the paragraphs that have such problems. How can I make sure that the overflow has been fixed? LaTeX still complains about it but I have `draft` passed to my document class and visually it looks like everything is fine. However, I want to be 100% sure that nothing is flowing into the margin.

Comment: If that is a comma separated list of differrent numbers, there should be a space between them, making it breakable.

Comment: @Johannes_B: it's actually a list of tuples which isn't breakable. the real question is how to detect overflow after using `sloppypar`

Comment: I assume you're getting Overfull `\hbox`es though. From there you can see what the overflow amount is, and one which page it occurs. Visually there might be no problem with something under .5pt, but that still is a problem.

Comment: You can add `\setlength{\overfullrule}{2pt}` in your preamble, which should show a `2pt` thick rule in the margin if there is any overflow in your document.

Comment: every overfull box is logged in the log, so you should always be 100% sure that isn't happening, just by looking at the log.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Just to be clear, even if I wrap things in `sloppypar`,  and for some reason it doesn't work, the overfill will be listed in the log file, correct?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: also I get some underfill boxes with a large badness. does this mean my text is simply too small to fit the hbox?

Comment: overfull boxes are reported unless you set hfuzz to suppress the warnings, but \sloppy basically says that you'd rather have very big white space to avoid overfull boxes. without any example it's really hard to give useful advice. if your numeric string is unbreakable and wider than than text width then it will naturally be overfull, otherwise using \sloppy I'd expect it not to go overfull but to force surrounding lines to be underfull

Comment: @Werner -- simply adding `[draft]` to the `\documentclass` options would get the visible overfull rule output.

Comment: @Alex -- underfull box messages simply mean that the higher the number reported (with 10000 being the highest available), the wider the gaps.  but nothing beyond the margin.  however, now that you explain it as a string of numbers that isn't breakable, it may well be possible to have an overfull line (or more).

Comment: @barbarabeeton: thanks! i will take a look at the specific instances in the paper. my main concern was the margin breakage as the publisher is very strict about that